# Указать лист с которым работать через GET запрос

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Доброго дня
Есть скрипт который записывает 4 параметра переданные через GET запрос в таблицу Google

запрос- 
[https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxWluI7PVOH9n0vQnQ3DX0yEtIqIRfJGvJ9aTLJDdS5uOmaMHw/exec?p1=данные&p2=еще&p3=ещеданные&p4=данные](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxWluI7PVOH9n0vQnQ3DX0yEtIqIRfJGvJ9aTLJDdS5uOmaMHw/exec?p1=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5&p2=%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5&p3=%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5&p4=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

```
function doGet(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1CikjuH1ZqXhvXUTRwTICd0u8DVtePSMpQ2ebv52Y8KU");
  var sheetname = sheet.getSheetByName('data');
  var n=sheetname.getRange("Z1").getValue()+2;
  var d = new Date(); 
  sheetname.getRange("A"+n).setValue(d);
  sheetname.getRange("B"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p1);
  sheetname.getRange("C"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p2);
  sheetname.getRange("D"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p3);
  sheetname.getRange("E"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p4);
  sheetname.getRange("Z1").setValue(n-1);
}
```

Он работает с листом под названием "data"

Как через тот же GET запрос указать название листа с которым нужно работать и подставить его в скрипт?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

[https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxWluI7PVOH9n0vQnQ3DX0yEtIqIRfJGvJ9aTLJDdS5uOmaMHw/exec?list=data&p1=данные&p2=еще&p3=ещеданные&p4=данные](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxWluI7PVOH9n0vQnQ3DX0yEtIqIRfJGvJ9aTLJDdS5uOmaMHw/exec?list=data&p1=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5&p2=%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5&p3=%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5&p4=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

```
function doGet(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1CikjuH1ZqXhvXUTRwTICd0u8DVtePSMpQ2ebv52Y8KU");
  var sheetname = sheet.getSheetByName(e.parameter.list); // здесь указываем лист
  var n=sheetname.getRange("Z1").getValue()+2;
  var d = new Date(); 
  sheetname.getRange("A"+n).setValue(d);
  sheetname.getRange("B"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p1);
  sheetname.getRange("C"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p2);
  sheetname.getRange("D"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p3);
  sheetname.getRange("E"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p4);
  sheetname.getRange("Z1").setValue(n-1);
}
```